# how to Update a field in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, sql-update, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am newbie in Cakephp so I feel difficulties to implement the database queries .. what i want is I want to update a mobile Number where email is equal to  the one the user has given .. 
this is the query which i want to implement

```
        "Update Users set  mobileNo = $mobileNo  where email = $email"
```

I am doing this

```
      $mobileNo = $data['mobileNo'];
        $email = $data['$email'];


        $count = $this->User->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array('User.email' => $email)));

        if($count>0){

            $email = $this->User->field(
                'email',
                array('User.mobileNo' => $mobileNo));
            echo $email;

            $this->User->saveField("mobileNo",$mobileNo);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Updates in CakePHP are normally all based around knowing the primary key of the records you want to edit.

### Normal/Simple

An example of updating a single field would be:

```
$this->User->id = $this->User->field('id', array('email' => $email));
if ($this->User->id) {
    $this->User->saveField('mobileNo', $mobileNo);
}
```

This would result in the following queries (some counts omitted):

```
SELECT id from users where email = "$email"
UPDATE users set mobileNo = "$mobileNo" where id = <id>
```

### Atomic

You can however perform exactly the same query as appears in the question using [updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions):

```
$this->User->updateAll(
    array('mobileNo' => "'$MobileNo'"),
    array('email' => $email)
);
```

This would result in the following queries:

```
UPDATE users set mobileNo = "$mobileNo" where email = "$email"
```

If you use updateAll pay attention that the update is expected to be sql fragments - that means you need to quote strings.